# Regex To Break Up camelCase String PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

Let say I have the following string:

```
getPasswordLastChangedDatetime
```

How would I be able to split that up by capital letters so that I would be able to get:

```
get
Password
Last
Changed
Datetime
```

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about ASCII characters:

```
$parts = preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/", $str);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/wEdFdcRu)

The `(?= ..)` construct is called [**lookahead** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

This works if the parts only contain a capital character at the beginning. It gets more complicated if you have things like `getHTMLString`. This could be matched by:

```
$parts = preg_split("/((?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=[A-Z][a-z]))/", $str);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/lYAjq3I5)

Answer (score 1):

Asked this a little too soon, found this:

```
preg_replace('/(?!^)[[:upper:]]/',' \0',$test);
```

Comment: I would add a **+**: `preg_replace('/(?!^)[[:upper:]]+/',' \0',$test);` to be able to get a good match on "getMyAPI". (That is, if you want the API as one word).

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
(?:^|\p{Lu})\P{Lu}*
```

Comment: More information can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: What do you propose to do with this regex?  If you use `preg_split` or `preg_replace`, the characters it matches will be deleted; if you use `preg_match_all`, everything *except* those characters will be deleted.

Comment: @Alan ? `preg_match_all` deletes nothing, it finds matches. You could e.g. do `preg_match_all('/(?:^|\p{Lu})\P{Lu}*/iu', 'getPasswordLastChangedDatetime', $result)`; then `$result[0]` will have the strings the OP wants.

Comment: You're right, I was reading the regex wrong.  And I should have said it would *ignore* the other characters, leaving them out of the results (but of course, it doesn't ignore anything).  But now I'm curious about that `i` modifier: it doesn't seem to have any effect in my tests--which is good, since case is the whole point.

Comment: @Alan I put the `i` accidentally (force of habit). In any case, since the expression is looking up the properties of the characters directly, it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

No need to over complicated solution. This does it

```
preg_replace('/([A-Z])/',"\n".'$1',$string);
```

This doens't take care of acronyms of course

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split('@(?=[A-Z])@', 'asAs')
```

Comment: FYI, there are no quantifiers and no dots in this regex, so the `U` (ungreedy quantifiers) and `s` (dot matches all) modifiers aren't doing any good.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*` or `\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*`

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_split("/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/",$password));
```