# Regex to split Camel case - with Numbers

Tags: java, regex, camelcasing

I want to split a camelCase name to individual names using regex, for performing a spell check.

The split should be as follows:

1) extendedStructureForNUB  --> extended, Structure, For, NUB

2) extendedStructureFor2004 --> extended, Structure, For, 2004

Using the answer from the below question , i am able to split for the 1st condition.

***Question*** : [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)

But for a string containing number (2nd condition), it is not returning as per format.

```
extendedStrctureFor2004 --> extended, Structure, For2004
```

Please suggest a way by which i can reuse this regex to split numerals also.

Comment: Hello2000WORLD --> Hello,2000, WORLD

Comment: MYNewString --> MY New String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{     
    for (String w : "camelValue".split("(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")) {
         System.out.println(w);
    } 
}
```

Edit: Correcting the case for UPPER2000UPPER the regex becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{     
    for (String w : "camelValue".split("(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<!(^|[^A-Z]))(?=[0-9])|(?<!(^|[^0-9]))(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")) {
         System.out.println(w);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Typo mistake. Checked and Working !! Thanks. Deleted my comment.

Comment: Fixed.  That's a lot of backtracking though.

Comment: Great Work. Perfect. Works in all conditions. "123IsJust345CheckNO678GOOD90" --> [123, Is, Just, 345, Check, NO, 678, GOOD, 90]

Comment: @DarenSchwenke Also can you please tell whether this much backtracking will affect performance?

Comment: Given your input string is words, and you are only going back up to a word at a time, probably not.  Benchmark if paranoid or just worry about it if it's too slow later.  <- me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (String w : "extended2004FeeStructure".split("(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")) {
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

corrected one

Comment: This will return [extended, 2, 0, 04, Fee, Structure] for extended2004FeeStructure. What i need is [extended, 2004, Fee, Structure]

Comment: Checked and Working !! Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

What I see is answer from your previous question was almost pervect. If I ware you i would just add another split opperation, but this time before first digit in middle in each word.

Here is example:

```
String data="2Hello2000WORLDHello2000WORLD";
//your previois split
String[] myFirstSplit=data.split("(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])");

//I will store split results in list (I don't know size of array)
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
for (String s:myFirstSplit){
    //if splited word contains digit after letter then split
    for (String tmp:s.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])"))
        list.add(tmp);
}
System.out.println(list);
//out [2, Hello, 2000, WORLD, Hello, 2000, WORLD]
```

Comment: This will work for in my case, but i am not sure how much performance efficient it will be. I need to compare all the variable names in a code base (which may easily contain thousands or lakhs of variable names) against a spell check dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

After you seperate this

extendedStrctureFor2004 --> extended, Structure, For2004

**Store it in some array like "arr"**

Use this **Regex**

**var numberPattern = /[0-9]+/g;
var numMatch= arr[i].match(numberPattern);**

now numMatch will contain the numerals u want..

Comment: This is about Java, not JavaScript.