# Regex to split String with uppercase and lowercharacter

Tags: java, regex, hashtag

I am trying to split like: `TwitterHashtagIsVeryCOMPLICATED`

The string after being splited like: `Twitter Hashtag Is Very COMPLICATED`

Could I use regex to do that?

Thanks so much for any advices.

Comment: you can what you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7593969/1578604).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
str.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")
```

The idea is to use zero-length lookbehind for a lowercase letter, and zero-length lookahead for the uppercase letter. This construct would match only at the "word breaks" in camel case strings.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/I6Qc35).

Comment: Perfect solution for ASCII ;) I don't know Twitter that much, can you use other things than ASCII letters in a twitter "id"?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you very much. It works and very intuitive with demo.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** *strongly* inspired by dasblinkenlight's answer (+1 for that). 
I only change to Unicode categories here for Unicode support:

```
String test = "TwitterHashtagIsVeryCOMPLICATED";
for (String splitted: test.split("(?<=\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu})")) {
    System.out.println(splitted);
}
```

Output:

```
Twitter
Hashtag
Is
Very
COMPLICATED
```

Comment: @HoaVu you're welcome. As fge mentions, I'm not sure whether Unicode characters are fully supported in hash tags. If they were, you might consider using Unicode categories instead of lowercase/uppercase ASCII character classes.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me any document that I can learn regex and the tool to test it so I can master regex by myself, rather than posting so much here :).

Comment: @HoaVu [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is my personal bible for Java regex reference. I recommend you peruse it. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) is the javadoc for the `Matcher` class - very useful as well. Finally [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is the Java regex essentials page. If you need more tutorials/examples, just google "java regex", there's plenty of really useful stuff. Good luck!