# Regex to split camel case

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in JavaScript to split my camel case string at the upper-case letters using the following code (which I subsequently got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)):

```js
"MyCamelCaseString"
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
    .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
```

Thus that returns:

```js
"My Camel Case String"
```

Which is good. However, I want to step this up a notch. Could someone help me with a regex which will split if, and only if, the former character is lower-case and the latter is upper-case.

Thus, the above example will be the result I expect, but if I do:

```js
"ExampleID"
```

Then I get returned:

```js
"Example ID"
```

Instead of

```js
"Example I D"
```

Since it's splitting at each upper-case and ignoring anything before it.

Hope that makes sense! And thanks :).

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: `(advanced)` -- sweet.

Comment: The result should be " My Camel Case String"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)

Comment: Try `replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')`

Comment: I removed "(advanced)" from the title in case people wonder what @devnull is talking about. It didn't really belong.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

My guess is replacing `/([A-Z])/` with `/([a-z])([A-Z])/` and `' $1'` with `'$1 $2'`

```
"MyCamelCaseString"
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

`/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/` for numbers counting as lowercase characters

```js
console.log("MyCamelCaseStringID".replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2'))
```

Comment: @keldar This won't work for numbers though. `Test1Test2` would stay the same.

Comment: Even more generally: `console.log('File1NotFoundTBA'.replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2'));`.

Comment: Should be noted the examples are not camel case which would have the first letter lower case. If this is expected to produce more of a title from true camel case string then you will still need to uppercase the first letter with one more line: 
`str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);`

Comment: Although this answers the OPs question, it doesn't handle `ThisIsASlug` or `Test1Test2`. You would get results like `This Is ASlug` and `Test1Test2` instead of `This Is A Slug` and `Test1 Test2`.

Comment: how does it work though, we only specify $1 and $2 and it is working even when we have many many camel case examples.

Comment: @Exploring the /g is the so called global flag, it means every match of said pattern will be replaced, not just first one.

Comment: Nice but the string is PascalCase .__.

Answer (score 49):

```
"MyCamelCaseString".replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g, '$1 ')
```

outputs:

```
"My Camel Case String"
```

Comment: `'ThisIsASlug'.replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g, '$1 ')` gives `"This Is ASlug"`

Comment: Nice but the string is PascalCase .__.

Comment: @JsonKody Nope, `camelCase` can be `CamelCase` but `PascalCase` can´t be `pascalCase`

Comment: @Legna ... and that's exactly why when you see 'ThisString', it's clearly identifiable as PascalCase, but it's not just 'camelCase with an initial capital letter'. In this instance, although the sets of what constitutes PascalCase and camelCase intersect, it's important to note that while this naming convention is standard for PascalCase, it's an atypical or less common occurrence for camelCase.

Answer (score 28):

If you want an array of lower case words:

```
"myCamelCaseString".split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(s => s.toLowerCase());
```

If you want a string of lower case words:

```
"myCamelCaseString".split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(s => s.toLowerCase()).join(' ');
```

If you want to separate the words but keep the casing:

```
"myCamelCaseString".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

Comment: Wasn't aware regular expressions worked inside the split function. I used a join after the split in my case. Super simple.

Comment: Putting it all together to handle the more advanced cases: `'File1NotFoundTBA'.split(/(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/)` gives `[ 'File1', 'Not', 'Found', 'TBA' ]`.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson - but `'ThisIsASlug'.split(/(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/)` gives `["This", "Is", "ASlug"]`. Would be better if it returned `["This", "Is", "A", "Slug"]` instead. Eugene's solution can handle this case.

Comment: I wish it also split `ThisIsASlug` to `This Is A Slug`. Unfortunately, I'm getting `This Is ASlug` with this solution.

Comment: @kimbaudi Then just use the original version above: `'ThisIsASlug'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)`.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson, using `'ThisIsASlug'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)` gives me `["This", "Is", "A", "Slug"]`, but it doesn't work well for `ExampleID`. `'ExampleID'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)` will return `["Example", "I", "D"]`. So I'm not going to use either.

Comment: Good point. Eugene's answer is probably best if your definition of camel case allows uppercase acronyms: `'ThisIsASlugWithAnExampleID'.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(w => w)`

Answer (score 23):

Sometime camelCase strings include abbreviations, for example:

```
PDFSplitAndMergeSamples
PDFExtractorSDKSamples
PDFRendererSDKSamples
BarcodeReaderSDKSamples
```

And in this case the following function will work, it splits the string leaving abbreviations as separate strings:

```
function SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations(s){
   return s.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(function(e){return e});
}
```

Example:

```js
function SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations(s){
   return s.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(function(e){return e});
}

console.log(SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations('PDFSplitAndMergeSamples'));
console.log(SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations('PDFExtractorSDKSamples'));
console.log(SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations('PDFRendererSDKSamples'));
console.log(SplitCamelCaseWithAbbreviations('BarcodeReaderSDKSamples'));
```

Comment: This is by far the most thorough.  The filter is to remove the empty strings.  You should add [0-9] on the lower case stuff, but this is definitely the final answer.  The others fail on abbreviations in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 5):

I found that none of the answers for this question really worked in all cases and also not at all for unicode strings, so here's one that does everything, including dash and underscore notation splitting.

```js
let samples = [
  "ThereIsWay_too  MuchCGIInFilms These-days",
  "UnicodeCanBeCAPITALISEDTooYouKnow",
  "CAPITALLetters at the StartOfAString_work_too",
  "As_they_DoAtTheEND",
  "BitteWerfenSie-dieFußballeInDenMüll",
  "IchHabeUberGesagtNichtÜber",
  "2BeOrNot2Be",
  "ICannotBelieveThe100GotRenewed. It-isSOOOOOOBad"
];

samples.forEach(sample => console.log(sample.replace(/([^[\p{L}\d]+|(?<=[\p{Ll}\d])(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}\d])|(?<=[\p{L}\d])(?=\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}\d]))/gu, '-').toUpperCase()));
```

If you don't want numbers treated as lower case letters, then:

```js
let samples = [
  "2beOrNot2Be",
  "ICannotBelieveThe100GotRenewed. It-isSOOOOOOBad"
];

samples.forEach(sample => console.log(sample.replace(/([^\p{L}\d]+|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=[\p{Ll}\d])(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=[\p{L}\d])(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll}))/gu, '-').toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to capitalize and add space between numbers as well, this works.

```
transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): string {
    const str = 'this1IsASampleText';
    str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1); // Capitalize the first letter
    str.replace(/([0-9A-Z])/g, ' $&'); // Add space between camel casing
}
```

Results:

```
This 1 Is A Sample Text
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

Comment: @kimbaudi I've updated the code. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: What do the args do here? what abou the value if it then uses a const str inside?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I saw no live [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUalGZbP9yR082vxgMNR?p=preview) , thanks [@michiel-dral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681964/michiel-dral)

```js
var tests =[ "camelCase",
             "simple",
             "number1Case2",
             "CamelCaseXYZ",
             "CamelCaseXYZa" 
           ]

function getCamelCaseArray(camel) {
  var reg = /([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g;
  return camel.replace(reg, '$1 $2').split(' ');
}

function printTest(test) {
document.write('<p>'+test + '=' + getCamelCaseArray(test)+'</p>');
}

tests.forEach(printTest);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `'ThisIsASlug'.replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2').split(' ')` gives `["This", "Is", "ASlug"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Regex not-a word boundary `\B` character can also be used

```js
console.log("MyCamelCaseString".replace(/(\B[A-Z])/g, ' $1'));
```

Comment: but `'ExampleID'.replace(/(\B[A-Z])/g, ' $1')` gives me `Example I D`. i wish it gave me `Example ID` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 'threeBlindMice'
a.match(/[A-Z]?[a-z]+/g) // [ 'three', 'Blind', 'Mice' ]
```

is the simplest way I've found, for simple camel/titlecase splitting.

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and had a camelCase value such as:

`thisIsMyCamelCaseValue` where the first letter is lowercased

```
function fromCamelCase(value) {
    const spaced = value.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
    return spaced.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + spaced.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to work with arrays over strings. It's easier to debug and more flexible. This is an actual `join` instead of `replace`. I haven't dealt with white spaces in the strings but you could just trim each element easily enough.

```js
const splitCamelCase = str => str.match(/^[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*|[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g).join(' ');

console.log(splitCamelCase('fooMyCamelCaseString'));
console.log(splitCamelCase('MyCamelCaseString'));
console.log(splitCamelCase('XYZMyCamelCaseString'));
console.log(splitCamelCase('alllowercase'));
```

Comment: but `'ExampleID'.match(/^[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*|[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g).join(' ')` gives me `Example I D`. I wish it would give me `Example ID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `regEx`, `replace`, and `trim`.

```
"ABCMyCamelCaseSTR".replace(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)/g, ' $1 ')
                   .replace(/\s{2}/g," ").trim()

// ABC My Camel Case STR
```

Comment: since you added `0-9` into your regex, it would be nice to also provide an example string containing numeric characters (ex: `"ABCMy22Camel123CaseSTR"` returning `"ABC My22 Camel123 Case STR"`)

Comment: also, your solution doesn't handle lowerCamelCase strings. `"ExampleID".replace(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)/g, ' $1 ').replace(/\s{2}/g," ").trim()` returns `Example ID`, but `exampleID` would still return `exampleID` instead of `example ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this question and needed to do the exact same thing:

*employeeID* should be rendered as *Employee ID*

I found this [convert case library](https://github.com/zellwk/javascript/tree/master/convert-case) from [zellwk](https://github.com/zellwk) plus a little additional reduce function did the trick for me:

```
import { toTitle } from "./convert-case.js";

// NB. Assumes sequential single chars can be concatenated
// ex. N B A Finals => NBA Finals
const reducer = (total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) => {
  if (
    currentValue.length === 1 &&
    !(currentIndex > 0 && arr[currentIndex - 1].length > 1)
  ) {
    return total + currentValue;
  } else {
    return total + " " + currentValue;
  }
};

const concatSingleChars = (title) => {
  const arrTitle = title.split(" ");
  return arrTitle.reduce(reducer);
};

const convertCase = (str) => {
  const s = toTitle(str);
  return concatSingleChars(s);
};

const tests = [
  "colName",
  "This_Is_A_title",
  "And_How_About_thisOne",
  "MaryHadALittleLamb",
  "employeeID",
  "N B A Finals",
  "N B A Finals in L A",
  "I Love L A"
];

const titles = tests.map((test) => {
  return convertCase(test);
});

console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got from Github Copilot — the explanation is mine, this is not fully AI generated —:

1. Put a space in front a capital letters via the `/([A-Z])/g` regex.
2. Capitalize whatever is at the beginning of the string via the `/^./` regex.
3. Trim the leading and trailing white space with the `.trim()` method.

Here is the final code:

```js
function camelCaseToCapitalized(str: string) {
  return str
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
    .replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase())
    .trim();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This RegExp String is

```
.replace("/([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)/g",...);
```