# Create object by grouping camelCase properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Recently I've found that I have had to create a object from attributes on a HTML tag. I am doing this in a AngularJS environment, so hyphenated attributes are converted to camelCase, but I could also do the same using `data-` attributes and `dataset`

So for example I have:

```
<element person-name="Grant" animation-jump="123" />
```

Which gives the object

```
{
   "personName" : "Grant",
   "animationJump" : "123"
{
```

My problem is that I then want to convert that camelCase object into a structured object:

```
{
  "person" : {
    "name" : "Grant" },
  "animation" : {
    "jump" : "123" }
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle of my QUint Unit Test https://jsfiddle.net/gdt3bonw/
It's actually working for the case I want which is only 1 level, but I would like to get it working for any number of levels because I foresee that it will be needed and so I can release the code publicly.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572)  (except for using camelcase instead of dots to join/split nested property names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will loop through the keys of the object using `reduce`, building up the result. We decompose each key into its components, such as `personName` into `person` and `name`. We loop over these components, creating subobjects if they do not already exist. Finally, we add the final component to the innermost subobject as a property with the value in question.

```
Object.keys(input).reduce((result, key) => {
  var parts = key.match( /(^|[A-Z])[a-z]+/g) . map(part => part.toLowerCase());
  var leaf = parts.pop();
  var obj = result;

  parts.forEach(part => obj = obj[part] = obj[part] || {});
  obj[leaf] = input[key];

  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Have removed the ECMA bit - Do you think you could edit my JSFiddle?

Comment: You should test with `deepEqual`.

Comment: This solution breaks if there are two or more consecutive capitals in the camelCase attribute such as `"fancyGirlTakesARide"`. It only takes the last consequent capital into account. So no `a` object is created for the above attribute.

Comment: Sure, and it fails for `fancyGirlWritesCSS`. You have to decide what you want the behavior to be in that case. If you want individual upper-case letters to be individual properties, then replace the `+` after the `[a-z]` with a `*`. If you want segments to allow multiple adjacent upper case letters, then add a `+` after the `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Well i guess you decide either to separate the consecutive capitals or to treat them as one, but definitely not throw all of them away up until the one that's followed with a lowercase (if exists) This would be loss of information. So accordingly correct regexes are either `/(^|[A-Z])[a-z]*/g` or `/(^|[A-Z]+)[a-z]*/g` but not the one in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that in this way, and I don't think that it would be a logic proposal. Below I explain why it wouldn't.

```
obj[["animation","jump"]] = "123"
```

replace it with

```
obj["animation"]["jump"] = "123"
```

and it's all fine.

Why I don't support your idea?

- It's messy to use, there is no style in doing that.
- There is no logic in using an array as an object key
- There is another way of calling an object item by key: using a dot, and that won't support your idea. I think everyone can imagine why.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to convert the attribute to camelCase in the first place..? Just do

```
function arrayToStructuredObject(obj,props){
  if (props.length){
    obj[props[0]] = props.length > 1 ? {} : value;
    arrayToStructuredObject(obj[props.shift()],props);
  }
  return obj;
}

var props = "animation-jump-tremendous-pinky".split("-"),
    value = "123", 
      obj = {},
     sobj = {};
sobj = arrayToStructuredObject(obj, props);
```

Besides i would like to remind that using the bracket notation to create a property is only possible if the reference that the bracket notation is used upon is predefined as an object. Such as

```
var o1; // <- undefined
o1["myProp"] = 1; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'myProp' of undefined
```

while

```
var o2 = {}; // Object {}
o2["myProp"] = 1; // <- 1
```

then again

```
o2["myProp"]["myOtherProp"] = 2; // <- 2 but won't type coerce o2.myProp to Object
```

So speaking of proposals, i am not sure if utilizing bracket notation directly over undefined variables yet as another object creation pattern makes sense or not.

Well in any case one complete solution would be

```
var inp = {"personName" : "Grant", "animationJump" : "123", "fancyGirlTakesARide" : "987"},
 result = Object.keys(inp).reduce(function(p,c,i){
                                    var props = c.replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => "-" + m.toLowerCase()).split("-");
                                    return arrayToStructuredObject(p,props,inp[c])                    
                                  },{});

function arrayToStructuredObject(obj,props,val){
  if (props.length){
    obj[props[0]] = props.length > 1 ? {} : val;
    arrayToStructuredObject(obj[props.shift()],props,val);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Though I loved the method of splitting the camelCase props by a look-ahead (`/?=[A-Z]/`) it takes an extra job of lower casing the whole array of prop strings regardless they are already lowercase or not. So i guess this might be slightly faster. (..or not due to the recursive nature of it)

Comment: I my real world case I am using AngularJS which converts hyphenated attributes to camelCase

Comment: @Luke T O'Brien Well in case you must definitely deal with camelCase props then above i have modified my solution into a complete one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but you can actually use arrays as key, in this particular situation, by converting them to a string:

```
obj[["animation","Jump"].join()] = "123";
```

This will work with your original object.

Answer (score 0):

A solution, which uses [Regex to split camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20381799/1447675) string.

```js
var obj = { "animationsJump": "123", "animationsRun": "456", "animationsHide": "789", "personName": "Grant", "personPetsDog": "Snowy", "personPetsCat": "Snowball" },
    newObject = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
    var path = k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function (s) {
            return s.toLowerCase();
        }),
        last = path.pop();
    path.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = r[a] || {};
        return r[a];
    }, newObject)[last] = obj[k];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nice use of lookahead in split regexp.