# How to add a space between camel case key name?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mailgun, nodemailer

I've created a node.js website that potential employees can apply for a job through. When they submit the application form I am using nodemailer and mailgun to send an email to the hiring manager with the applicants information. It sends the object of the new applicant with the key value pairs, but I would like to put a space between the keys containing more than one word and make them uppercase to be a little more eye pleasing. How can I do this?

here is a sample email with output key value pairs

[image]

Here is the code for sending an email

```
function sendAppliedEmail(applicant) {


let html = '<img src="" alt="logo">';
  html += '<h2 style="color: black">New Applicant</h2>'
  html += '<ul>';

  Object.entries(applicant).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    html += `<li>${key}: ${value}</li>`;
  });

  html += '</ul>';
```

Comment: Here is an answer on converting camel case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225407/convert-camelcasetext-to-sentence-case-text

Comment: Did you want the initial character capitalized as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379254/regex-to-split-camel-case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, `$1 $2`)
```

You can replace all lowerUpper matches.

Everytime a lowercase character followed by a uppercase character, the regex match and replace the both characters with themself and a space between.

```js
function sendAppliedEmail(applicant) {


let html = '<img src="" alt="logo">';
  html += '<h2 style="color: black">New Applicant</h2>'
  html += '<ul>';

  Object.entries(applicant).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    html += `<li>${key.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, `$1 $2`)}: ${value}</li>`;
  });

  html += '</ul>';
```

if the key should be complete uppercase you can chain the `toUpperCase()` method to the replace method.

```js
html += `<li>${key.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, `$1 $2`).toUpperCase()}: ${value}</li>`;
```

Comment: Nice job on the simplicity of this! Mine was similar but I wasn't sure if the initial character needed to be capitalized :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Awesome answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the replace function to ascertain if a letter is upper case and return a prefixed space with the character if it is, while simultaneously making sure that the first character is capitalized.

```
key.replace(/[a-z]/gi, (m, o) => (m < {} && o) ? ` ${m}` : (o) ? m : m.toUpperCase())
```

---

### Brief Explanation

You can determine whether or not a character is capitalized by comparing it to `{}`. If a character is *less than* it is capitalized, and if it is *greater than* it is lower case. This is because `{}` will be transformed to the string `[object Object]`, and both the character codes will be compared. Upon comparison only the first character will be used("["). Thus `"A" < "["` and `"A" < {}` is equivalent. This is easier explained through seeing their character codes:

```
"A".charCodeAt(0);
 //65
"[".charCodeAt(0);
 //91
"a".charCodeAt(0);
 //97
```

(In fact, it's more performant to use "[", and for optimization you would compare to that instead. It's simply easier to remember "{}" is greater than capital characters and vice versa)

### *Why do this?*

In typical RegEx you could simply use `[A-Z]` to grab capitalized characters, but the caveat is that if you're looking to capitalize the first character AND space camel case, this comparison in addition to the `offset` parameter( think of it as an index of the string ) in the `replace` function allows you to do so in a **singular pass through the string.**

---

### An Example:

```js
let splitCase = key => key.replace(/[a-z]/gi, (m, o) => (m < "[" && o) ? ` ${m}` : (o) ? m : m.toUpperCase());

let key = "phoneNumber";
console.log(splitCase(key));

key = "firstName";
console.log(splitCase(key));
```

---

### In Your Code:

The below snippet is **non-functioning**, but it should work within your code:

```js
function sendAppliedEmail(applicant) {
let splitCase = (key) => key.replace(/[a-z]/gi, (m, o) => (m < "[" && o) ? ` ${m}` : (o) ? m : m.toUpperCase());

let html = '<img src="" alt="logo">';
  html += '<h2 style="color: black">New Applicant</h2>'
  html += '<ul>';

  Object.entries(applicant).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    html += `<li>${splitCase(key)}: ${value}</li>`;
  });

  html += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slit them on the uppercase character with a regex. See this question: [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)