# Split a string by Uppercase as long as the each word is not all caps already

Tags: c#

I need to split a [*CamelCase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) string into an array of words based on the case of the letters.  The rules for dividing the string are as follows:

- Break the string in all places where a lowercase letter is followed by an uppercase letter, and break **before the uppercase letter**.

  - e.g.: `aB` -> `{ "a", "B" }`
  - e.g.: `helloWorld` -> `{ "hello", "World" }`
- Break the string in all places where an uppercase letter is followed by a lowercase letter, and break **before the uppercase letter**.

  - e.g.: `ABc` -> `{ "A", "Bc" }`
  - e.g.: `HELLOWorld` -> `{ "HELLO", "World" }`

Some edge cases deserve examples of expected output:

- `FYYear` -> `{ "FY", "Year" }`
- `CostCenter` -> `{ "Cost", "Center" }`
- `cosTCenter` -> `{ "cos", "T", "Center" }`
- `CostcenteR` -> `{ "Costcente", "R" }`
- `COSTCENTER` -> `{ "COSTCENTER" }`

I've tried using a regular expression as shown in the code below:

```cs
updateCaption = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(updateCaption, @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])"));
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What if you had something like `cosTCenter`?

Comment: Or `CostcenteR`

Comment: Or `COSTCENTER`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your problem statement may not be well defined.

Comment: What makes FYY required to split on FY and Y?  Is it that there are three CAPS together?

Comment: This question does not seem too broad to me.  I'm surprised this is on hold.  There's a specific problem definition and expected input and output.  Alas, something needs to be done, so I'll take a shot at rewriting it to be more concise.  Hopefully still in alignment with @tvb108108's intent.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you Wyck for your comments. Thought I provided enough information of what I needed to do. Your updates look great and is worded a lot better.

Comment: @wyck all yours now...

Comment: Probably worth referencing some great solutions in other languages:  [JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379358/1563833) and [Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7594052/1563833).  You can craft a C# implementation that uses the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```cs
static IEnumerable<string> SplitCamelCase(string input)
{
   return Regex.Split(input, @"([A-Z]?[a-z]+)").Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
}
```

It works by splitting the string using "an uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letters" (or just one or more lowercase letters) as a delimiter.  `string.Split` will include the delimiters in the result array if they are captured in parentheses (and they are, in my example).  And this leaves only the spans of capital letters (all but the last) occurring between delimiters, which `string.Split` will include in the array naturally.  It does produce superfluous empty strings in some cases, but they can be filtered out; I did so with a `.Where` clause.

It's not bad.  I only wish there were a nicer way to eliminate the empty strings more easily.

By the way, I elected to return `IEnumerable<string>` because I feel like that format is more reusable. But you can always `.ToArray()` the result if you prefer an array, or the result can be joined with spaces using `string.Join(" ", result)` to form your corrected string.

Here's a complete demonstration:

```cs
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<string> SplitCamelCase(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"([A-Z]?[a-z]+)").Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] examples = new string[] {
            "FYYear",
            "CostCenter",
            "cosTCenter",
            "CostcenteR",
            "COSTCENTER"
        };
        foreach (string str in examples) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0, 10} -> {1}", str, String.Join(" ", SplitCamelCase(str)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    FYYear -> FY Year
CostCenter -> Cost Center
cosTCenter -> cos T Center
CostcenteR -> Costcente R
COSTCENTER -> COSTCENTER
```

Answer (score 3):

This RegEx should do the trick:

```
private string ToUppercase(string input) {
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])");
    return regex.Replace(input, " ");
}
```

I copied the formatting from https://regex101.com/r/ahah3D/2 for further explanation:

[image: regex formatted]

There are two matching groups considered here. The first positive lookbehind looks for any uppercase letter followed by any (uppercase or lowercase) letter. The second one tests for your standard case i. e. a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter.

Let me know if that solves your question.