# How to split a camel case string containing numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have camel cased strings like this:

```
"numberOf40"
"numberOf40hc"
```

How can I split it like this?

```
["number", "Of", "40"]
["number", "Of", "40hc"]
```

I am using [humps](https://github.com/domchristie/humps) to decamelize keys so I can only pass a `split` regex as option. I am looking for an answer that only uses `split` function.

My best attempts:

```
const a = "numberOf40hc"

a.split(/(?=[A-Z0-9])/)
// ["number", "Of", "4", "0hc"]

a.split(/(?=[A-Z])|[^0-9](?=[0-9])/)
// ["number", "O", "40hc"]
```

Also I don't understand why the `f` is omitted in my last attempt.

Comment: You don't say what the logic is but I think you shouldn't use split for this since the rule is not simple.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379254/regex-to-split-camel-case

Comment: @Hogan I'm using the library Humps to decamelize keys and the only option I can use is a `split` regex

Comment: @evolutionxbox no there is no numbers in it

Comment: @adesurirey -- you are using a javascript library that does not let you execute a lambda on the data -- I doubt it.

Comment: from the documentation --> "It also accepts a callback which can modify the conversion behavior."  https://www.npmjs.com/package/humps

Comment: @Hogan yes I saw it but I prefer not rewriting the whole logic if I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get the `f` in you last attempt `(?=[A-Z])|[^0-9](?=[0-9])` as this part of the last pattern `[^0-9]` **matches** a single char other than a digit and will split on that char.

You could also match instead of split

```js
const regex = /[A-Z]?[a-z]+|\d+[a-z]*/g;

[
  "numberOf40",
  "numberOf40hc"
].forEach(s => console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[0])));
```

Using split only, you could use lookarounds with a lookbehind which is gaining more browser support.

```js
const regex = /(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/g;

[
  "numberOf40",
  "numberOf40hc"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.split(regex)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const a = "numberOf40hc"

let b = a.split(/(\d+[a-z]*|[A-Z][a-z]*)/).filter(a => a);

console.log(b);
```

The `.filter(a => a)` is necessary because `split`, returns both the left and right side of a matched delimter. E.g. `'a.'.split('.')` returns both the left (i.e. `'a'`) and right (i.e. `''`) side of `'.'`.

Per your update regarding the need for compatibility with `humps`, it seems `humps` supports customizing the handler:

```js
const humps = require('humps');

let myObj = {numberOf40hc: 'value'};

let decamelizedObj = humps.decamelizeKeys(myObj, key =>
        key.split(/(\d+[a-z]*|[A-Z][a-z]*)/).filter(a => a).join('_'));

console.log(decamelizedObj);
```

Comment: He wants the last element to be `40hc` not `hc`

Comment: Thank you but I am using Humps.js to decamelize keys so I can only pass a `split` regex. I am looking for an answer that only uses `split`. I edited my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const splitStr = (str='') =>
  str.split(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/).filter(e => e);
console.log( splitStr("numberOf40") );
console.log( splitStr("numberOf40hc") );
```

Comment: Thank you but I am using Humps.js to decamelize keys so I can only pass a `split` regex. I am looking for an answer that only uses `split`. I edited my question to be clearer.