# write regex for PMD custom rule

Tags: xml, xpath, pmd

i created the following custom rule for PMD but when i run it, i get an error. if i replace the regex with a trivial regex like "a", it works. cannot understand what's wrong.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ruleset name="Custom Rules"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 https://pmd.sourceforge.io/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

    <rule name="LongMethodName"
        language="java"
        message="Method name too long"
        class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule">
        <description>
            Method name should be composed by less that five words
        </description>
        <priority>4</priority>
        <properties>
            <property name="version" value="2.0" />
            <property name="xpath">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                    //MethodDeclaration[count(tokenize(@Name, '(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')) + 1 > 5]
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

the error i get is the following. get an error for each file in the project i'm analyzing

```bash
Nov 04, 2022 10:45:42 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSet apply
WARNING: Exception applying rule LongMethodName on file /Users/francescobresciani/MSDE/1sem/software-design-modeling/sdem-ass2/fastjson-master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/fastjson/parser/SymbolTable.java, continuing with next rule
java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Error at character 1 in regular expression "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])": expected ())
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.xpath.SaxonXPathRuleQuery.initializeXPathExpression(SaxonXPathRuleQuery.java:272)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.xpath.SaxonXPathRuleQuery.evaluate(SaxonXPathRuleQuery.java:113)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule.evaluate(XPathRule.java:176)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule.apply(XPathRule.java:158)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSet.apply(RuleSet.java:670)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSets.apply(RuleSets.java:163)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:209)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCodeWithoutCache(SourceCodeProcessor.java:118)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:100)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:62)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call(PmdRunnable.java:89)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call(PmdRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Error at character 1 in regular expression "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])": expected ())
        at net.sf.saxon.java.JRegularExpression.<init>(JRegularExpression.java:70)
        at net.sf.saxon.java.JavaPlatform.compileRegularExpression(JavaPlatform.java:198)
        at net.sf.saxon.functions.Matches.tryToCompile(Matches.java:218)
        at net.sf.saxon.functions.Tokenize.maybePrecompile(Tokenize.java:45)
        at net.sf.saxon.functions.Tokenize.simplify(Tokenize.java:36)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.FunctionCall.simplifyArguments(FunctionCall.java:100)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.FunctionCall.simplify(FunctionCall.java:88)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.BinaryExpression.simplify(BinaryExpression.java:45)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ArithmeticExpression.simplify(ArithmeticExpression.java:42)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.BinaryExpression.simplify(BinaryExpression.java:45)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.FilterExpression.simplify(FilterExpression.java:130)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.SlashExpression.simplify(SlashExpression.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionVisitor.simplify(ExpressionVisitor.java:159)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionTool.make(ExpressionTool.java:74)
        at net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator.createExpression(XPathEvaluator.java:167)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.xpath.SaxonXPathRuleQuery.initializeXPathExpression(SaxonXPathRuleQuery.java:269)
```

i tested the regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works.
i tested the XPath expression on [xpather](http://xpather.com/) and it looks valid
i tested the XPath expression on [freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and it looks **NOT** valid. it says: `Unable to perform XPath operation. Syntax error at char 1 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier`

the following is the snippet i checked the XPath rule against

```xml
<root>
 <MethodDeclaration Name="shortName"/>
 <MethodDeclaration Name="thisMethodNameIsVeryVeryLong"/>
</root>
```

the following is the exact string i input in xpather and freeformatter
`//MethodDeclaration[count(tokenize(@Name, '(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')) + 1 > 5]`

Answer (score 0):

The leading character in your regular expression, `(`, marks the start of a group.

The next character, `?`, is a "quantifier" (like `*` or `+`); it specifies how many times the preceding expression may occur (it means "either zero or one"). But there is no preceding expression.

Are you trying to match the literal character `?`? If so, you should escape it like so `\?`.

Are you trying to match the literal character `(` either zero or one time? If so, you should escape *that* character `\(` so it's not interpreted as the start of the group.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that the Positive Lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) and Positive Lookahead (`(?=...)`) is not supported by the Regex Syntax in XPath (at least XPath 2.0). The supported Regex syntax is described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs - and the tokenize function in XPath 2.0 is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-tokenize - This doc also contains some more infos about the regex in XPath.

Searching for an alternative solution, I found the question [Regex to split camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379254/regex-to-split-camel-case)

The general idea is: First replace every lower case character immediately followed by an upper case character with the same characters including a space in between and then tokenize (splitting) the resulting string by that space.

This works with the following XPath:

```
//MethodDeclaration[count(tokenize(string(replace(@Name, '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2')), ' ')) + 1 > 5]
```

The conversion to a string (the `string(...)` function call) is only required by http://xpather.com/ - but it doesn't hurt. The expression also works with PMD.

Here's the example: http://xpather.com/f9SD9WMX