# Struggling with regex code: CamelCase to camel_case

Tags: c#, regex

I was able to transform the string `MyClassName` to `my_class_name` using a regex

However my solution did not work with `MyOtherTClassName`, that should transform to `my_other_t_class_name`.

Also, this didn't work on `ClassNumber1` either, which should be transformed into `class_number_1`

Without getting into my solution, that was not good enough, I would like help with the regex code that transforms:

1. `MyClassName` -> `my_class_name`
2. `MyOtherTClassName` -> `my_other_t_class_name`
3. `MyClassWith1Number` -> `my_class_with_1_number`

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: Your samples are inconsistent (why is `CLass` treated as `Class`?), and you need to show your 'not good enough' attempts.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes i think MyOtherTCLassName was meant to be MyOtherTClassName , guy is this correct ?

Comment: I thought that as well until I saw the same 'mistake' made twice.

Comment: Why not post your existing solution to the first problem? If it solves the first case I can't imagine the next case(s) would be that hard to expand it to.

Comment: Here's a post of someone doing this exact thing in Python: [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to camel_case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)

Comment: I'm partial to [my solution to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7599674/433790).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic behind is that you want to convert every capital letter to its lower-case variant and preceed it (and every number) with an underscore.
For example a `T` becomes `_t`, `6` becomes `_6`.
The only exception is the very first character. You don't want to preceed it with an undersoce. The regex will handle this case with a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to not match the first character.

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpression

//your input
string input = "MyOtherTClass1Name";

//the regex
string result = Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    "((?<!^)[A-Z0-9])", //the regex, see below for explanation
    delegate(Match m) { return "_" + m.ToString().ToLower(); }, //replace function
    RegexOptions.None
);
result = result.ToLower(); //one more time ToLower(); for the first character of the input

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For the regex itself:

```
(           #start of capturing group
  (?<!      #negative lookbehind
     ^      #beginning of the string
  )         #end of lookbehind
  [A-Z0-9]  #one of A-Z or 0-9
)           #end of capturing group
```

So we capture every capital letter and every number (except for the very first character) and replace them with a lower-case variant of themselves combined with a preceeding underscore.

Comment: What if there is a sequence of multiple upper case letters (like HTML?) You could add a negative lookahead as well

Comment: As the OP wanted every occurence of (i.e) `A` gets replaced with `_a`. So in case of multiple upper case letters each and every of them gets replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and the previous answer works if there's only one digit but if there are two or more consecutive digits they each would have an underscore preceding them. I used this to convert it for me in PHP.

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])|(?<![0-9])([0-9])/', '_$1$2', $string))
```

The regex, I believe, should be the same as C# so I'll break that down.

```
(?<!       # negative look behind
   ^       # beginning of string
)
([A-Z])    # one of capital letters
|          # or
(?<!       # negative look behind
   [0-9]   # one of digits
)
([0-9])    # one of digits
```

The idea is the same for letters. Make sure it's not the beginning of the string. For the digits just make sure that the previous character is not also a digit. We don't have to worry about it being the beginning of a string because the string won't start with a digit.