# Format a string containing no spaces using java

Tags: java, string, function

Any ideas how to effeciently convert the String "TDMaturityReinvestOnNotSelected" to "TD Maturity Reinvest On Not Selected" using a java function?

Cheers
Shaun

Comment: Some, what have you tried?

Comment: Is the first letter of each word always in uppercase?

Comment: How would you do it at [Pen Island Pens](http://penisland.net/)? And yes, that site is a joke.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 3):

This brilliant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced#answer-7594052) to [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced) should work nicely.

Below is an excerpt from that  answer:

```
final String pattern = "(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])";
for (String w : "TDMaturityReinvestOnNotSelected".split(pattern)) 
{
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

And the ouput to show it running:

[image: Test output from demo code]

***Edit:***  You'll need to reassemble the split words with spaces, but that should be trivial to work out.