# how to extract words from a String like "thisIsMyString" in Java

Tags: java, string

I have to deal with Strings like: "hasCityName" , "hasAddress", "hasNumberOfStreet".

What I need is to extract the words from those Strings, so if we have: "hasNumberOfStreet", I would like to get: "has", "Number" , "Of" and "Street".

Is there any function for this? or I should go through the string checking when the char changes to uppercase/lowercase and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check with substring/indexOf?

Comment: Split the string using regex on uppercase letters

Comment: Check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex `(?=[A-Z])`

```
str.split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

1. `[A-Z]` indicates splitting from a capital letter
2. `?=` is a positive lookahead that is required to keep the delimiter.

---

Code

```
String str = "hasNumberOfStreet";
String spStr[] = str.split("(?=[A-Z])");

for(String s : spStr) System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
has
Number
Of
Street
```

Comment: Here you are not taking into account "has", right?. Useful anyway, thank you!

Comment: @AntonioSerrano `has` is the first string and it will automatically get splitted from first delimiter. There's no need to handle it .

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the below regex for splitting the string

```
<<your string>>.split("(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")
```

Comment: This looks intriguingly complex, you clearly know your regex, could you explain what each part is doing?

Comment: This was what I wanted, thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Approach with regex is good but if you need to do it without regex in a simple way you can use `Character.getType(charAt) == Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER` check to find index of uppercase letter and extract preceding word:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String in = "hasNumberOfStreetD";
        String in = "hasNumberOfStreet";
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastUpperCaseIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            char charAt = in.charAt(i);
            if (Character.getType(charAt) == Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER) {
                words.add(in.substring(lastUpperCaseIndex, i));
                lastUpperCaseIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (lastUpperCaseIndex < in.length()) {
            words.add(in.substring(lastUpperCaseIndex, in.length()));
        }
        words.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Prints:

```
has
Number
Of
Street
```