# Perl regular expression to split string by word

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which consists of several words (separated by Capital letter).

For example:

```
$string1="TestWater"; # to be splited in an array @string1=("Test","Water")
$string2="TodayIsNiceDay"; # as @string2=("Today","Is","Nice","Day")
$string3="EODIsAlwaysGood"; # as @string3=("EOD","Is","Always","Good")
```

I know that Perl easily split uses the split function for fixed character, or the match regex can separate $1, $2 with fixed amount of variable. But how can this be done dynamically? Thanks in advance!

That post [Spliting CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced) doesn't answer my question, my question is more related to regex in Perl, that one was in Java (differences apply here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)

Comment: Not duplicate, there are differences between java regex and perl regex. But thanks for checking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using `m//g` in list context, which returns a list of all matches found. (Rule of thumb: Use `m//g` if you know what you want to extract; use `split` if you know what you want to throw away.)

Your case is a bit more complicated because you want to split `"EODIs"` into `("EOD", "Is")`.

The following code handles this case:

```
my @words = $string =~ /\p{Lu}(?:\p{Lu}+(?!\p{Ll})|\p{Ll}*)/g;
```

I.e. every word starts with an uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}`) and is followed by either

- 1 or more uppercase letters (but the last one is not followed by a lowercase letter), or
- 0 or more lowercase letters (`\p{Ll}`)

Comment: I really like your answer, very neat. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Use [split](http://p3rl.org/split) to split a string on a regex. What you want is an upper case character not followed by an upper case character as the boundary, which can be expressed by two look-ahead assertions ([perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre) for details):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;

sub split_on_capital {
    my ($string) = @_;
    return [ split /(?=[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))/, $string ]
}

is_deeply split_on_capital('TestWater'),       [ 'Test', 'Water' ];
is_deeply split_on_capital('TodayIsNiceDay'),  [ 'Today', 'Is', 'Nice', 'Day' ];
is_deeply split_on_capital('EODIsAlwaysGood'), [ 'EOD', 'Is', 'Always', 'Good' ];

done_testing();
```

Comment: Why doesn't that produce empty leading elements for `TestWater` and `TodayIsNiceDay`?

Comment: @melpomene: Documented in [split](http://p3rl.org/split):  zero-width match at the beginning of EXPR never produces an empty field