# php split string by capital letter but ignore TLA. Also with TLA at the end of the word

Tags: php, regex, string, split

The solution can apparently be this:

```
$string = 'TodayILiveInTheUSAWithSimon';
$regex = '/(?<!^)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))/';
$string = preg_replace( $regex, ' $1', $string );
```

But this case "TodayILiveInTheUSAWithSimonUSA" does not work well because it returns "Today I Live In The USA With Simon **US A**" the last letter appears separated. Do you know a complete solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)

Comment: You may use: [`(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/X3gIix/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!^)(?![[:upper:]]$)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))
```

Added in a negative lookahead to make sure it isn't matching the capital at the end of the string too.

The only times you'll want to separate this is if you're ending on a one letter word anyway, which is unlikely, so shouldn't have too much backlash

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip all 3 uppercase letters then using PHP (PCRE) you may be able to use this regex:

```
(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])/';

$result = preg_replace($re, ' ', $str);
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]{2}(*SKIP)(*F)`: If we match 2 uppercase letters and have a uppercase letter at previous position then skip (fail) that pattern
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])`: If have any letter at previous position and have a uppercase letter at next position

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `(?:[A-Z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)\K(?=[A-Z])` **Substitution**:  `" "` (space)

**Details**:

- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `|` Or
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match.
- `(?=)` Positive Lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ekiAf0/1)

**Code**:

```
$text = 'TodayILiveInTheUSAWithSimon';
$text = preg_replace("/(?:[A-Z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)\K(?=[A-Z])/", " ", $text);
print_r($text);
```

**Output**: `Today I Live In The USA With Simon`