# Third Party API Integration in Python / Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

```
import requests
r = requests.get('some url')
data = r.text
```

> {"NumberOfPassedStudents":"21061","TotalAttendedCandidates":"74494","NumberOfEnrolledStudents":"84308"}

The above output I got it looks like a `dictionary` but it is not a `dictionary` it is a `Unicode` . My question is I want to get output in the below mention way

> > Number of Passed Students : 21061 
> >       Total Attended Candidates : 74494 
> >     Number of Enrolled Students : 84308

What is the code in python 2.7 to convert those Unicode into my desire above mention output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the in-built `json()` method to convert your HTTP response data to a python `dict` when you have a content-type of `application/json`.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://someurl.com')
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> result = r.json()
>>> result
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

If you have another content type, you can use the `json` module to convert the return string / unicode into a python `dict`

```
import json, requests

r = requests.get('some url')
result = json.loads(r.text)
```

Then you can get your desired output by treating your result as a `dict`

```
print 'Number of Passed Students : %s' % result['NumberOfPassedStudents']
print 'Total Attended Candidates : %s' % result['TotalAttendedCandidates']
print 'Number of Enrolled Students : %s' % result['NumberOfEnrolledStudents']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
data={"NumberOfPassedStudents":"21061","TotalAttendedCandidates":"74494","NumberOfEnrolledStudents":"84308"}
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    print re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2",k) +" : "+ v
```

**output**

```
Number Of Passed Students : 21061
Total Attended Candidates : 74494
Number Of Enrolled Students : 84308
```

Comment: my output looks like dictionary but it is a unicode.

Comment: convert unicode object in to json using json.loads(), then process the dictionary

Comment: Get the key from the dictionary and find the capital letter occurrences from the key string and consider it as word starting then adding the space.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a dict's key-values you should use `items()` method:

```
my_dict = {'a':'foo', 'b':'bar'}
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
     print key, value
```

this prints

```
a foo
b bar
```

for split that CamelCase go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916065/how-to-do-camelcase-split-in-python)