# regex Python: split CamelCase AND STOP IF there is space

Tags: regex

All help is greatly appreciated folks
I found a brilliant solution here [How to do CamelCase split in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916065/how-to-do-camelcase-split-in-python) ,

- `re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', string)).split()`

However I need it to stop IF THERE is SPACE
Example

- `t = 'YankeesMets'` **>>> `['Yankees', 'Mets']`**
- `tt = 'CubsWhite Sox'` >>> **`['Cubs', 'White']` (no more words after the first whitespace)**

So, how do I change regex to STOP splitting CamelCase if it finds space?

Comment: What is the current output for `CubsWhite Sox` and what is the expected output?

Comment: NO, I only need it to return Cubs, White and stop there

Comment: Current output is ['Cubs', 'White', 'Sox']... I expect it to be  ['Cubs', 'White']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the part of the string from its beginning to the first whitespace and apply your solution to that part of the string:

```py
re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', text.split()[0])).split()
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/u3ABq5), and the [following demo](https://ideone.com/ZTbZG2) below:

```py
import re
l = ['CubsWhite Sox', 'YankeesMets']
for s in l:
    print(f"Processing {s}")
    first = s.split()[0]
    result = re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', first)).split()
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
Processing CubsWhite Sox
['Cubs', 'White']
Processing YankeesMets
['Yankees', 'Mets']
```