# Looking for Regex pattern to return similar results to my current function

Tags: python, regex, pascalcasing

I have some pascal-cased text that I'm trying to split into separate tokens/words.
For example, `"Hello123AIIsCool"` would become `["Hello", "123", "AI", "Is", "Cool"]`.

## Some Conditions

- "Words" will always start with an upper-cased letter. E.g., `"Hello"`
- A contiguous sequence of numbers should be left together. E.g., `"123"` -> `["123"]`, not `["1", "2", "3"]`
- A contiguous sequence of upper-cased letters should be kept together *except* when the last letter is the start to a new word as defined in the first condition. E.g., `"ABCat"` -> `["AB", "Cat"]`, not `["ABC", "at"]`
- There is no guarantee that each condition will have a match in a string. E.g., `"Hello"`, `"HelloAI"`, `"HelloAIIsCool"` `"Hello123"`, `"123AI"`, `"AIIsCool"`, and any other combination I haven't provided are potential candidates.

I've tried a couple regex variations. The following two attempts got me pretty close to what I want, but not quite.

## Version 0

```py
import re

def extract_v0(string: str) -> list[str]:
    word_pattern = r"[A-Z][a-z]*"
    num_pattern = r"\d+"
    pattern = f"{word_pattern}|{num_pattern}"
    extracts: list[str] = re.findall(
        pattern=pattern, string=string
    )
    return extracts

string = "Hello123AIIsCool"
extract_v0(string)
```

```py
['Hello', '123', 'A', 'I', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

## Version 1

```py
import re

def extract_v1(string: str) -> list[str]:
    word_pattern = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"
    num_pattern = r"\d+"
    upper_pattern = r"[A-Z][^a-z]*"
    pattern = f"{word_pattern}|{num_pattern}|{upper_pattern}"
    extracts: list[str] = re.findall(
        pattern=pattern, string=string
    )
    return extracts

string = "Hello123AIIsCool"
extract_v1(string)
```

```py
['Hello', '123', 'AII', 'Cool']
```

## Best Option So Far

This uses a combination of regex and looping. It works, but is this the best solution? Or is there some fancy regex that can do it?

```py
import re

def extract_v2(string: str) -> list[str]:
    word_pattern = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"
    num_pattern = r"\d+"
    upper_pattern = r"[A-Z][A-Z]*"
    groups = []
    for pattern in [word_pattern, num_pattern, upper_pattern]:
        while string.strip():
            group = re.search(pattern=pattern, string=string)
            if group is not None:
                groups.append(group)
                string = string[:group.start()] + " " + string[group.end():]
            else:
                break
    
    ordered = sorted(groups, key=lambda g: g.start())
    return [grp.group() for grp in ordered]

string = "Hello123AIIsCool"
extract_v2(string)
```

```py
['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your Version 1:

```py
import re


def extract_v1(string: str) -> list[str]:
    word_pattern = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"
    num_pattern = r"\d+"
    upper_pattern = r"[A-Z]+(?![a-z])"  # Fixed
    pattern = f"{word_pattern}|{num_pattern}|{upper_pattern}"
    extracts: list[str] = re.findall(
        pattern=pattern, string=string
    )
    return extracts


string = "Hello123AIIsCool"
extract_v1(string)
```

Result:

```py
['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

The fixed `upper_pattern` will match as many uppercased letters as possible, and will stop one before a lowercased letter if it exists.

Comment: I was so close! Thank you. +1

Comment: Assigning to `extracts` and then returning `extracts` seems needlessly verbose. As does `pattern=pattern` and `string=string`.

Comment: Assigning return value to a named variable is likely a good habit, for it'll make debugging easier and the additional time cost may typically be several nanoseconds which is almost neglectable. I agree with you on not using those keywords though.

Answer (score 2):

use `re.sub` and `split()`

```
import re

def pascal_case_split(identifier):
    return re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([0-9]+)', r' \1', identifier))).split()

a = pascal_case_split("Hello123AIIsCool")
a
```

```
['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916065/how-to-do-camelcase-split-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall` should do the trick with much less work on your part. With `re.X` to allow for spacing out the pattern a bit.

```
>>> re.findall(
...   r'( [A-Z]{2,} (?! [a-z] ) | \d+ | [A-Z] [a-z]+ )', 
...   'Hello12 3AIIsCool', 
...   re.X
... )
['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

| Pattern | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[A-Z]{2,} (?! [a-z] )` | Matches two or more capital letters, *not* followed by a lowercase letter. |
| `\d+` | One or more numbers. |
| `[A-Z] [a-z]+` | A single uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letters. |

As noted in comments, the first subpattern does not match a single capital letter. We can amend this by replacing `[A-Z]{2,}` with `[A-Z]+` to match *one or more* capital letters not followed by a lowercase letter.

Comment: Wow. Not sure how that one got past me. Thanks.

Comment: A key difference between this answer and the others is the `[A-Z]{2,}`. If I used the example string from [Hao Wu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78235635/6509519), this fails to capture the single "A" in "IsAMarkup". Changing it to `{1,}` or `+` makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this regex:

```
[A-Z](?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z]))?|\d+
```

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/Xe1tLy/2)

```
import re

pattern = r"[A-Z](?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z]))?|\d+"
text = "Hello123AIIsCoolAndHTML5IsAMarkupLanguage"

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
# ['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool', 'And', 'HTML', '5', 'Is', 'A', 'Markup', 'Language']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain what the `?:` does? And the `?!`

Comment: `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group, I use it here to groups several OR conditions without leaving a back-reference. `(?! ... )` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), the following text must NOT match the pattern inside.

Comment: Linking to [a pretty good explanation on non-capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/6509519).

Answer (score 0):

Seems easier to do backwards:

```py
import re

def extract(string: str) -> list[str]:
    backwards = re.findall(r'[a-z]+[A-Z]|\d+|[A-Z]+', string[::-1])
    return [s[::-1] for s in backwards[::-1]]

string = "Hello123AIIsCool"
print(extract(string))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3r2fmFuQXlSgUpXJxpaSmKaRWlBQlJpdoFJcUZealWykAaU0FXTuFnMzikmggJ9aKSwEIkhKTs8sTi1KKFWyBWvXSMvNSEnNyNIrUoxN1q2K1ox11o2JrYlK0a8AsbXUdBYiB0VZWuoaxmmAzilJLSovyFKKLIYIKaflFCsUKmXkIwyESsVxcEM1Au5Q8UnNy8g2NjB09PYud8_NzlLgKgFIlGqju1tSEeA_qS5hvAQ)):

```
['Hello', '123', 'AI', 'Is', 'Cool']
```