# Title Tags for Static Pages when using header include

Tags: php, html

am creating some static pages for a client (they didn't want a cms) that all share a header and footer php files. 
***I need to create title and meta description tags for individual pages but am not sure how to do this if they all share the same php head section.***

I suppose on the individual pages I could leave the closing head tag and place the title tags above. seems like there would be a cleaner solution?

Just to clarify, I don't need to echo the title tag based on the url. I want to be able to individually add title/description/keyword tags to each page and then get those dynamically from the head.php

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789430/dynamic-title-of-page-php-include-links

Comment: NO, that solution spits out the current url as the title tag, and there's not solution to do dynamic meta tags as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the page title in as a parameter to a function:

```
function makeHead($title) {
    echo "<title>" . $title . "</title>";
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

The `makeHead` function would be defined in `header.php`. Then when you want to include a head to a page, simply do:

```
include "header.php";

makeHead("Title of page");

... more stuff ...
```

I use this method whenever I'm making a static PHP site.