# Proper Case a non space words with case like "ILovePHP" on php

Tags: php

is there any way to make a proper case of these words on PHP?
Eg:

- ILovePHP -> I Love PHP
- HelloWorld -> Hello World
- HTMLIsFun -> HTML Is Fun

Comment: This is only possible , if you have set of dictionary words and then do a comparison. There is no native PHP function to do this as far as I know.

Comment: Here you can write a function to detect non consecutive upper case char and put a space before.

Comment: i think i found a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519739/split-camelcase-word-into-words-with-php-preg-match-regular-expression. My problem solved from there. Never known a "camel case" before. thanksa all