# Adding space to string based on condition

Tags: php, string

I have a load of labels which are camel case.  Some examples are

```
whatData
whoData
deliveryDate
importantQuestions
```

What I am trying to do is this.  Any label which has the word Data needs to have this word removed.  At the point of the capital letter, I need to provide a space.  Finally, everything should be uppercase.  I have done the removal of Data and the uppercase by doing this ($data->key is the label)

```
strtoupper(str_replace('Data', '', $data->key))
```

The part I am struggling with is adding the spaces between words.  So basically the above words should end up like this

```
WHAT
WHO
DELIVERY DATE
IMPORTANT QUESTIONS
```

How can I factor in the last part of this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4519739/4323504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will add spaces before every capital letters. Try this:

```
$String = 'whatData';
$Words = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $String);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

- Your regex `'~^[A-Z]~'` will match only the first capital letter. Check out Meta Characters in the Pattern Syntax for more information.
- Your replacement is a newline character `'\n'` and not a space.

**Solution**

Use `preg_replace()`. Try below code.

```
$string = "whatData";   
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $string);
```

**Output**

```
what Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$string = 'importantQuestions';
$string = strtoupper(ltrim(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ' $0', $string)));
echo $string;
```

This will give you output as:

> IMPORTANT QUESTIONS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_split:  split on camel case
array_map:   UPPER case all the element
implode:     Implode the array
str_replace: Replace the `DATE` with empty
trim:        trim the white spaces.
```

Do this simple things:

```
echo trim(str_replace("DATE", "", implode(" ", array_map("strtoupper", preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'deliveryDate', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))))); // DELIVERY
```

> This is result exactly what you want.