# how to convert camel case to upper english words in php

Tags: php

I have different strings that are function names like

```
createWebsiteManagementUsers
```

I want to change them into

```
Create Website Mangement Users
```

How can i achieve that in PHP?

Comment: You can preg replace capitals with space followed by match and then capitalize the first letter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519739/split-camelcase-word-into-words-with-php-preg-match-regular-expression

Comment: preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $String); will check for the capital letter in the string and insert space. Then by using ucwords you can make it camel case. please check my answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

a) You can use `ucwords()`:-

```
echo ucwords($string);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/sCiEJ

b) In your expected outcome spaces are there, if you want them as well, then do like below:

```
echo ucwords(implode(' ',preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'createWebsiteManagementUsers')));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/v3KUK

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$data = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'createWebsiteManagementUsers');

$string = implode(' ', $data);

echo ucwords($string);
```

output will be

> Create Website Management Users

Comment: I also need the spaces in between.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code to solve:

```
$String = 'createWebsiteManagementUsers';
$Words = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $String);
echo ucwords($Words);

//output will be Create Website Mangement Users
```

Comment: Don't need to escape the space - `'/(?<! )[A-Z]/'`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need. This has the spaces as well!

```
function parseCamelCase($camelCaseString){
    $words_splited = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$camelCaseString);
    $words_capitalized = array_map("ucfirst", $words_splited);
    return implode(" ", $words_capitalized);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry i'll follow up on the promise :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function camelCaseToString($string)
{
    $pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$string);
    $word = implode(" ", $pieces);
    return ucwords($word);
}

$name = "createWebsiteManagementUsers";
echo camelCaseToString($name);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this

```
//Split words with Capital letters
$pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'createWebsiteManagementUsers');

$string = implode(' ', $pieces);

echo ucwords($string);
```

//You will get your desire output **Create Website Management Users**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/((?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]+)/',$str,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

**100%** Most **Efficient** :

```
$word = 'camelCase'; // expected: Camel Case
$sentence = modifyWord($word);

function modifyWord($word)
{
    $splittedWord = str_split($word);
    $modifiedSentence = ucwords($splittedWord[0]);

    for($i = 1; $i < count($splittedWord); $i++){

        // ASCII : A => 65, Z => 90
        // check if the letter is between A & Z

        if(ord($splittedWord[$i]) >= 65 && ord($splittedWord[$i]) <= 90){
            $modifiedSentence .= ' '.$splittedWord[$i];
        }else{
            $modifiedSentence .= $splittedWord[$i];
        }
    }
    
    return $modifiedSentence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version with UPPER letter check and symbols

```
<?php
$word = 'UniCredit Bank (AA)'; // expected: Camel Case
$word = 'CamelCase with space (CAPITAL_NAME) and strangEEword'; // expected: Camel Case
$sentence = modifyWord($word);

echo $sentence;

function modifyWord($word)
{
    $splittedWord = str_split($word);
    $modifiedSentence = ucwords($splittedWord[0]);

    for($i = 1; $i < count($splittedWord); $i++){

        // ASCII : A => 65, Z => 90
        // check if the letter is between A & Z
        
        $nextCapital = isset($splittedWord[$i+1]) && ord($splittedWord[$i+1]) >= 65 && ord($splittedWord[$i+1]) <= 90;
        $prevCapital = isset($splittedWord[$i-1]) && ord($splittedWord[$i-1]) >= 65 && ord($splittedWord[$i-1]) <= 90;
        

        if(ord($splittedWord[$i]) >= 65 && ord($splittedWord[$i]) <= 90 && !$nextCapital && !$prevCapital){
            $modifiedSentence .= ' '.$splittedWord[$i];
        }else{
            $modifiedSentence .= $splittedWord[$i];
        }
    }
    
    return $modifiedSentence;
}
```