# How do I get just the words from my array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a PHP variable `$MostRecentQuestionType` whose value is `SimplifyingFractions`. I want to print `Simplifying Fractions`, so I tried the following, but it returns `Array ( [0] => Simplifyin [1] => Fractions )`

```
$MostRecentQuestionType = $data['MostRecentQuestionType'];
$MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded = preg_split('/.(?=[A-Z])/',$MostRecentQuestionType);
print_r($MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded);
```

How do I extract the words from this array?

Side note: I know people are going to attack me for not doing my research; I've tried but I don't quite have the vocab to look up the solution. I've tried `converting array to string` and similar searches, but the results don't address this question. My searching has led to me to `preg_replace`, `str_replace`, `toString()`, among others, but nothing seems to help. I feel like I'm getting hung up on something that has a very easy solution.

Comment: Look at the other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519739/split-camelcase-word-into-words-with-php-preg-match-regular-expression

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$MostRecentQuestionType = "SimplifyingFractions";
$MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$MostRecentQuestionType);
print(implode($MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded," "));
```

You could also cut out the middle man by doing:

```
<?php
$MostRecentQuestionType = "SimplifyingFractions";
$MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded = preg_replace('/(?=[A-Z])/'," ",$MostRecentQuestionType);
print($MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded);
```

Comment: Ah, I KNEW it had to be something simple like this. Thanks so much! I'll accept the answer when the site allows me to do so in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your print_r command, you can do this :

```
 foreach($MostRecentQuestionTypeExploded as $value)     { print($value." ");}
```

Comment: This doesn't even run; based on his code you're attempting to iterate a string with a foreach loop??

Comment: $MostRecentQuestionType at this point of the script is an array, since the preg_split() command was called just before.

Comment: `preg_split` is not an in place operation, `$MostRecentQuestionType` is a string. And even if it was, he wanted an output of a string, not dumping the array values. His issue was how the string was being split.

Comment: Alright the stackoverflow app bugged as always and didn't take into account my edit. Forgot the Exploded, hence the confusion.