# Regular expression capture groups which is in a group

Tags: java, regex

In Java, how to get all groups which is inside a group (regular expression).
For example:Using **(([A-Z][a-z]+)+)([0-9]+)** test a string : "AbcDefGhi12345".
Then get Result:
matches():yes
groupCount():3
group(1):AbcDefGhi
group(2):Ghi
group(3):12345

But I want to get String "Abc", "Def", "Ghi", "12345" respectively. 
How can I do that by using regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions cannot handle repeating groups it can return any of the captured groups (in your case it returned `"Ghi"`).

The example below will print:

```
Abc
Def
Ghi
12345
```

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String example = "AbcDefGhi12345";

    if (example.matches("(([A-Z][a-z]+)+)([0-9]+)")) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(example);

        String m;
        while ((m = s.findWithinHorizon("[A-Z][a-z]+", 0)) != null)
            System.out.println(m);

        System.out.println(s.findWithinHorizon("[0-9]+", 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the camelCaseStyle define each group?

Comment: @pringlesinn: Yes (the word-groups).

Comment: @dacwe: so maybe what I asked a while ago might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502273/breaking-strings-into-chars-that-are-in-upper-case

Comment: -1 if you copy my (and hzh's) answer you should mention it and not add a comment that it would not work.

Comment: An RE engine may return the first place it matches each group instead. There's no actual specification for what's produced in that case (and it's a very black art at the RE matcher level anyway).

Comment: @dacwe: Cool! (There's no spec because it depends on how the matcher works. Java appears to be using a stack-based one, which places the match late, but automata-theoretic ones place the match early. Both are “correct”, and the differences emphasize that REs aren't the solution to everything.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]+|(?:[0-9]+))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AbcDefGhi12345");
while(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: If matching strings that does not start with `[A-Z][a-z]+` is okey it is the best solution!

Answer (score -1):

like hzh's answer with some format and a little bit simpler:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]+"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("AbcDefGhi12345"); 
while(m.find()){ 
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); 
}
```

gives you

```
Abc
Def
Ghi
12345
```

Comment: Not true, when I run it I get the following: 1. Abc
2. Def
3. Ghi
4. 12345

Comment: Yes, it still matches the string "12345" alone which is **not** ok.

Comment: Why is it not ok???? The OP never required it to match only strings that are in some kind of format. And giving me a -1 for that... hmmm.

Comment: If so, putting a if(string.matches("([A-Z][a-z]+)+[0-9]+")) {} around will help of course.