# regular expression multiple characters within or

Tags: regex

is it possible to capture only multiple characters within 'or'?

i would like this `[(abc)(cde)]`
to capture `abc or cde` however it captures `( or a or b or c or ) ...`

i saw this: [regular-expression-capture-groups-which-is-in-a-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537191/regular-expression-capture-groups-which-is-in-a-group)

is what i'm asking not possible in regular expressions? it sounds too obvious and far needed, for me not to exist in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
(abc|cde)
```

This matches either `abc` or `cde` and captures the result in a backreference. If you don't need the backreference, use

```
(?:abc|cde)
```

Another hint: If you want to make sure that you only match entire words, not substrings within a longer word like `abc` within `tabcontrol`, use word boundaries:

```
\b(abc|cde)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

`(abc|cde)` should work for you.